# How to populate a dropdown button using a function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a function that returns the items I need to use to populate the dropdown button. I tried calling the function inside the dropdown button on the items property but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a minimal code snippet?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html are you trying to do something like this?